# MySQL secondary index of timestamp type misses data

Tags: mysql, sql-timestamp

Mysql version is 5.1.46. And the table looks like

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_createTime` (`createTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This query do works, it finds the data normally

```sql
select * from user where (createTime>='2022-04-25 16:11:48') and (createTime<='2022-04-25 16:11:49');
```

But this query not, it returns a empty result.

```sql
select * from user where (createTime>='2022-04-25 16:11:48.0') and (createTime<='2022-04-25 16:11:49.0');
```

I `explain` them, and found that only the values of `rows` are different, the rows value of the second sql is 1.

I noticed that mysql 5.1 does not support fraction. This may be the reason why the range query fails.
But when I try this query,

```sql
select * from user where createTime='2022-04-25 16:11:48.0';
```

it works normally. That's weird.
It feels like the secondary index has a problem with the range query of timestamp

By the way, Mysql 8.0 does not have this problem.

Comment: Did you try `createTime >= CAST('2022-04-25 16:11:48.0' AS TIMESTAMP)` ?

Comment: Does the second (fractional) query work without index on `createTime` in MySQL 5.1?

Comment: @IVOGELOV   `select CAST('2022-04-25 16:11:48.0' AS TIMESTAMP);` is not a right SQL syntax.

Comment: ok, then `select TIMESTAMP('2022-04-25 16:11:48.0')` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV it works.But why?

Comment: @SinChang Because it probably returns `2022-04-25 16:11:48` (no fraction part) in your MySQL version.

Comment: @user14967413 Why does adding an index lead to different results?

Comment: @SinChang The comparison is probably implemented a bit differently when scanning index instead of table data. I think this problems appear only when you use this fraction timestamp, because it is unsupported format.